# Migrating Angular JS 1.6.10 to 1.7.8

Tags: angularjs, migration

I need to migrate my AngularJS version from 1.6.10 to 1.7.8. I would like to know will there be any code breakage after migration?

If anyone could provide the list of differences between 1.6.x and 1.7.x would be much more helpful.

Comment: did you referred these documents?
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Yes Jeff, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Migrating from (AngularJS) 1.6 to 1.7](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-6-to-1-7) contains the information you're looking for. The most notable changes are:

> - `$resource` has now support for request and requestError interceptors
> - Several deprecated features have been removed:
>
>   1. the `$controllerProvider.allowGlobals()` flag
>   2. the `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled()` flag
>   3. the `angular.lowercase` and `angular.uppercase` methods
>   4. the `$cookieStore` service from the `ngCookies` module
>   5. the `ngClick` override directive and corresponding services from the `ngTouch` module
>   6. the complete `ngScenario` module

In the linked resource there is also the full list of breaking changes.

The link for the specific version 1.7.8 is: https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.8/docs/guide/migration

Comment: Thanks @lealceldeiro It's really helpful.